# Adding logging/tracing to an MSSQL trigger

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I wrote a trigger for a table in an Azure SQL Server instance. I was wondering how I can add some kind of tracing/logging to the trigger so I can actually see what trigger does... 
I'm getting a strange error which I can't really place, and the trigger is rather complicated.

Comment: What's the error? Can you post the trigger?

Comment: you can debug the trigger in Sql Server Managment Studio

Comment: Without at least the error message we can't possibly help you. The trigger code would also be helpful. Without these details this is like taking your car to the shop and telling the guy "my car isn't working" and expecting them to figure out the problem.

Comment: @SeanLange actually, it's more like telling the guy at the shop your car isn't working, and not actually bringing the car.

Comment: I could have posted the trigger I suppose, but as I said, it was rather complicated one and I wasn't asking about the error, but on a way to add tracing/logging to the rigger. In the end I managed tracing the error by using print - statements. Not the cleanest way to do this, but OK.

Comment: @SeanLange I wasn't asking about the error... I was asking about the tracing.

Comment: @GuidoG Apparently you can't debug SSMS with Azure. That's the first thing I tried obiously.

Comment: I did not know that, sorry. That is another good reason to stay away from azure...

Comment: Well, it has some advantages, but it still has certain limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [PRINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) statements to the trigger. When you perform the appropriate insert/update/delete statement in SSMS the trigger will write the PRINT statements to the Messages tab.

You may want to identify in your PRINT statement which trigger is printing the statement as well as the output...nesting and multiple triggers per table can make some of these quite difficult to debug.

One other thing you can try is to fake inserted/deleted tables using table variables if you want to test individual parts of your trigger. Remember that the trigger may have to handle multiple rows at the same time!

Comment: Managed to trace the error using print statements. Just wished there was a more elegant way.

Comment: There is a debug option in SSMS but I haven't had much success with it...I never have sufficient permission on servers when I go to try it! You could have a flag somewhere in the database to turn on/off the print statements I suppose to avoid removing them but I haven't heard of a more elegant way. If someone was to let me know I would be all ears :-)

Comment: I do most of my SQL development in Visual Studio. You can also debug there, but like you I usually don't have sufficient access to the database to use it.